# How to convert device that uses OTG to communicate with Android device to Bluetooth?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, usb-host

We currently have a piece of hardware that uses an OTG cable to communicate with an  Android application. We are currently using USB Host to communicate with the Android device, but we hope to offer a Bluetooth feature for the project.

I was wondering, on the hardware aspect, how something like that could be achieved. We hope to connect to the Android device's Bluetooth. For that, I imagine we would need to build some circuitry that plugs into the external device and enables wireless communication.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how this can be done or resources to see. I have seen what some people do with wired mice, but they still have an OTG cable plugged into the Android device with a Bluetooth mouse dongle. We would like something that does not involve any wires connected to the phone.

Comment: Are you able to update the Android app to use Bluetooth APIs in place of the existing APIs providing access through USB (they'd be class-specific)?  Without modifying the Android app, your chances of completely avoiding an OTG connection are slim to none.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, we are planning to modify the Android app so that it supports both Bluetooth and wired connections. We will be using Bluetooth APIs.